# Cannot clear query cache after error globally

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I am using onError callback to show toast messsage globally. And I also want to clear all cache If user gets 401. But in error callback error and query parameters don't have any method to achieve this. How can I do it?

```
const queryClient = useMemo(
    () =>
      new QueryClient({
        queryCache: new QueryCache({
          onError: (error, query) => {
            handleToastErrorMessage(error);

            if (error.response.status === 401) {
              // I want to remove all queries from cache here
              // removeQueries();
            }
          },
        }), []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `queryClient` variable that you just have and its method `queryClient.clear()` will clear all connected caches.

Although you might want to use `queryClient.resetQueries()` instead to reset queries in the cache to their initial state, or even `queryClient.invalidateQueries()` to just refetch everything? It's up to you though.

[All the info is in the docs as always](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/QueryClient#queryclient)

Comment: I want to clear cache inside of new QueryClient's on error callback. How can I use queryClient inside of it? It hasn't created yet. It will be created after QueryClient returns.

Comment: You answered yourself, you can use it because it will be created at that point when something calls `onError`